# What is the difference between "hash" and "block hash" as is demonstrated in the data?

Tags: hash, blockchain-size, machine-learning

In the following data, there are two kinds of hashes. One is a *"hash"* variable and the other is a *"block hash".* While I sense that the latter should be the block header hash, **I do not understand what does the former signify?**

[image]

In the data there are as many as 137 records for the block no. '13418400'. While the "block hash" remains same for all of them, the "hash" varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At bitcoin, `hash` and `block hash` are same, but at Etherum, polygon etc. One Block contains data of multiple transactions.

Block is block hash &
Transaction data is hash.

This is done to save energy, money & storage in new varients of blockchain networks.

For example (see image below)
[image: polygonscan latest block]
This is currently the latest block of polygon matic chain. This block have data of multiple transactions.

But in bitcoin and other old blockchain's, there is only one transaction stored in one block.

Comment: Thank you @aakash4dev . I have accepted your answer. I am new to this technology. I shall be grateful if you could elaborate what does **"One Block contains data of multiple transactions"** mean?

Comment: Elaburated ✔️ (updated answer). Hope you understood.

Comment: Yes I did, thank you so much :)